# Create checkboxes with materializeCss cards in Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, materialize, ransack

I'm building a Rails app with some filters in it using Ransack, and I wan't that the users are able to search a property using cards like in the image below. When they select a card in my DB that will return.
[image]

**My Current Ransack form**

```
    <%= search_form_for @q, html: {autocomplete: 'off'}  do |f| %>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

               <!--APARTMENT CARD-->
                <div class="col l6 s6">
                    <div class="card-panel hoverable b-radius5px">
                        <img style="width:60px;" class="center" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/craftwebs/image/upload/v1584137944/condominium_pltgkr.svg" alt="">
                        <span class="center blue-grey-text text-lighten-2" style="margin-left: -15px;">Apartment</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--HOUSE CARD-->
                <div class="col l6 s6">
                    <div class="card-panel hoverable z-depth-1 b-radius5px">
                        <img style="width:60px;" class="center" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/craftwebs/image/upload/v1584138119/real-estate_mugxx7.svg" alt="">
                        <span class="center blue-grey-text text-lighten-2">House</span>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="center">
                    <%= f.submit "Search", class:" waves-effect blue-kafasa-bn waves-light btn b-radius15px" %>
                </div>
```

**Now, the only way Im able to search these properties is via select:**

```
<div class="col l6 m6 s12">
<%= f.select(:propertytype_eq, options_for_select(['Apartment', 'Office', 'House' ]), {:include_blank => 'Pick a property'} ) %>
 </div>
```

[image]

This is how it looks in my logs when I search for a specific property in my app using **select**:

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "q"=>{"price_gteq"=>"", "price_lteq"=>"", "propertytype_eq"=>"Apartment"}, "commit"=>"Search"}
```

### How Can I make that the users search a property by using cards and not a select? Do I need to modify the materialize checkbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try using onclick functions for the cards? You can add a onclick event that either initiates navigation or sets a flag/variable for the option you want.